# SICP example: Counting change, cannot understand

Tags: algorithm, recursion, scheme, sicp, coin-change

I am a beginner following SICP course on MIT OpenCourseWare using both the video lectures and the book available online. Yesterday I came across an example, which ask if we can write a procedure to compute the number of ways to change any given amount of money.

This problem has a simple solution as a recursive procedure:

```
(define (count-change amount)
  (cc amount 5))
(define (cc amount kinds-of-coins)
  (cond ((= amount 0) 1)
        ((or (< amount 0) (= kinds-of-coins 0)) 0)
        (else (+ (cc amount
                     (- kinds-of-coins 1))
                 (cc (- amount
                        (first-denomination kinds-of-coins))
                     kinds-of-coins)))))
(define (first-denomination kinds-of-coins)
  (cond ((= kinds-of-coins 1) 1)
        ((= kinds-of-coins 2) 5)
        ((= kinds-of-coins 3) 10)
        ((= kinds-of-coins 4) 25)
        ((= kinds-of-coins 5) 50)))
```

If you want to check more of it, I took it from [here](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.2).

they are calculating the number (N) of ways of change a quatity (A) using K kinds of coins by adding:

1. the number of ways (X) of changing A without coins of the first type.
2. The number of ways (Y) of changing (A - D), where D is the denomination of the fisrt coin, using ALL K types of coins.

The problem is, I just don't understand this. Following, they try to explain saying:

"To see why this is true, observe that the ways to make change can be divided into two groups: those that do not use any of the first kind of coin, and those that do. Therefore, the total number of ways to make change for some amount is equal to the number of ways to make change for the amount without using any of the first kind of coin, plus the number of ways to make change assuming that we do use the first kind of coin. **(Is the last sentence the same as the addition N = X + Y ? )** But the latter number is equal to the number of ways to make change for the amount that remains after using a coin of the first kind. **(After using this coin, they refer to ways of making change with or without the first kind of coin? )** "

I understand how they implemented the recursive algorithm, but I am unable to see how they got there. 
English is not my native language, so I might be missing something. If you could explain me, using other terms, the logic behind the solution I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: to your first question in bold: yes. to the 2nd: with it (re: "using ALL K types of coins"). what is still unclear?

Comment: @WillNess I understand it more clear now,thanks, Now, I'm unable to fully comprehend the part form the book which gives logic to the Y value in my question: "Therefore, the total number of ways to make change for some amount is equal to the number of ways to make change for the amount without using any of the first kind of coin, plus the number of ways to make change assuming that we do use the first kind of coin. **But the latter number is equal to the number of ways to make change for the amount that remains after using a coin of the first kind** Why is that? I cannot see it.

Comment: @nanameable, do use the first kind of coin can be restated do use at least a coin of the first kind in the same meaning. It is solved as (cc (- amount
                        (first-denomination kinds-of-coins))
                     kinds-of-coins)))))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we think too hard on recursion, we already fail. Personally, I use two metaphors in thinking recursions. One is from the small book "the little schemer": `The Seventh Commandment - Recur on the subparts that are of the same nature`. Another is the divide-conquer-combine paradigm for designing algorithms. Essentially, they are the same thing in how to think recursively.

1. Divide to the subparts of the same nature

The problem has two variables: The number (N) of money and the kinds (K) of coins, therefore any division needs to meet the following: `1. reducing all variables: both N and K, 2. the subparts are the same nature so each subpart can be solved by the recursion process itself or be can solved directly. 3. all subparts together == the original one part, no more and no less.`

The division in the solution divides the original problems into two subparts: the first subpart is all combinations that using the first coin (we can restate it that all combinations using at least one coin of the first coin in the same meaning). The remaining subpart is that all combinations using none of the first coin. N is reduced in the first subpart, K is reduced in the second part. Both are the same nature which can be solved recursively and they together are the original problem.

2. conquer

In this step, I think about the base cases. What are the all base cases when the problem is reduced to the minimal that can be given answers directly. In this solution, there are three base cases. 1st is the N is reduced to 0. 2nd is the N is reduced to the negative. 3rd is the coins is reduced to 0 but N is still positive.

3. combine

How results are combined when the subparts are solved. In this solution, they are simply +.

What's more, if we are recursive on a list, the division is usually car of the list and cdr of the list. Usually car of list can be solved directly if itself isn't a list. cdr part should be solved recursively. The base case is the end of list if met.

B.T.W, I would highly recommend `the little schemer` for learning recursion. It is much better than any others on this particular point as far as I have read.

Answer (score 30):

*"number (N) of ways ... using N kinds"* these two `N`s are clearly not the same. so let's say `K` kinds of coins.

We have many coins, but each coin is either 1, 5, 10, 25 or 50 cents, in total 5 kinds of coins. We need to buy something for a dollar, 100 cents. Assume unlimited supply of each kind of coins. How many ways are there for us to reach the total sum of 100?

We either use some coins (one or more) of 50 cents, or we don't. If not, we still have to get to the 100 with only 4 kinds of coins. But if we do, then after using *one* 50 cents coin, the total sum becomes 100 - 50 = 50 cents, and we may still use all 5 kinds of coins to reach the new, smaller total sum:

```
ways{ 100, 5 } = ways{ 100, 5 - 1 }      ;   never use any 50-cent coins
                 +                       ; OR
                 ways{ 100 - 50,  5 }    ;   may use 50-cent coins, so use one
```

Or in general,

```
ways( sum, k ) = ways( sum, k - 1 )
                 +
                 ways( sum - first_denomination(k),  k )
```

That's all there is to it. See? Generalization comes naturally with abstraction (replacing concrete values with symbols and making them parameters in the resulting function's definition).

---

Then we need to take care of the base cases. If `sum = 0`, the result is 1: there's one way to reach total sum of 0 (and it is: take no coins).

If `k = 0`, this means we are not allowed to use *any* kind of coins; in other words there's no way for us to reach a sum, *any* sum, without using at least *some* coins (unless the sum is 0, but we've already handled that case above). So the  result must be 0.

Same if `sum < 0`, of course. Impossible, i.e. 0 ways to sum up to it, using any coins with any positive denomination.

---

Another way to look at this is from the other end of the time arrow, if you will.

Imagine someone have already done all that for you and have put in front of you all these piles of bills, each pile summing up to the target sum. Without loss of generality, let each pile be sorted so that bigger bills are on top.

Divide all the piles into two groups: one with the biggest denomination bill on top each pile, and the other - without it. If the total number of piles is `ways( denomsList, targetSum)`, then clearly the number of piles in the *second group* is `ways( rest(denomsList), targetSum)`.

Then, we can get the top bill off each pile in the *first group*, and the number of piles in it clearly won't be changed by that. Having removed the top bill in each pile, we see that they all sum up to `targetSum - first(denomsList)`, hence they number `ways( denomsList, targetSum - first(denomsList))` in total.

---

The point to (structural) recursion is thinking in the small -- *not* trying to picture the whole sequence of operations at once, but rather standing still and trying to understand your *current* situation. It is a mental tool for approaching your problem, it is about solving it in the easiest most natural way, making *as small a step* as possible.

Calling ([a copy of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944969/prolog-accumulators-are-they-really-a-different-concept/19951540#19951540)) yourself  is a technicality. The main thing is the leap of faith, that you are *allowed* to call yourself: assuming you have already written down your definition, *just use it* were appropriate. And that's [how it gets written down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659581/functional-programming-lots-of-emphasis-on-recursion-why/12662393#12662393). You just describe what you have,  how it's made of *smaller* parts (some of them *similar* to the full thing), and how the *results* for *those* parts can be combined back with the rest to get the full solution.

---

*edit* (from comments): The key to solving a problem recursively is to recognize that it can be broken down into a collection of smaller sub-problems to each of which *that same general solving procedure that we are seeking* applies, and the total solution is then found in some *simpler* way from those sub-problems' solutions (which are found by that same general procedure as if it were available to us already). Each of thus created sub-problems being "smaller" guarantees the base case(s) will eventually be reached.

In other words, try to find the structure in the problem so that it has substructures similar to the whole (like fractals; or e.g. a list's suffix is *also* *a list*; a tree's branches are *also* *trees*; etc.); then, *recursive problem solving* is:

- *assuming* we already have the solution;
- *taking apart* the problem instance, according to the way in which the problem is structured;
- *transforming* the sub-problems which are similar to the whole problem, by that same solution; and then
- *building the whole result* back, combining the sub-results in some simpler constructive way.

The "trick" is to recognize the existing, *inherent* structure in your problem so that the solution comes naturally.

Or, in *Prolog* (of all the programming languages :) ) :

```ml
recursion(       In,  Out) :- 
  is_base_case(  In), 
  base_relation( In,  Out).

recursion(       In,  Out) :- 
  not_base_case( In),
  problem_parts( In,    SelfSimilarParts,      LeftOvers),  % (* take it apart *)
  maplist( recursion,   SelfSimilarParts,                   % (* go forth >>>  *)
                             InterimResults),
  result_parts(       Out,   InterimResults,   LeftOvers).  % (* and back <<<  *)
```

Which is to say, in pseudocode,

```ml
(In <--> Out) are related by recursion when
   either
      In is indivisible, and Out its counterpart
   or
      In  =:  Sub_1 <+> Sub_2 <+> ... <+> Sub_N  <++>  Shell
              ------  r e c u r s i o n  ------
      Out :=  Res_1 {+} Res_2 {+} ... {+} Res_N  {++}  Shell
        where
        (Sub_i <--> Res_i) ,  for each  i = 1, ..., N
```

The combination operation `+` for `In` and `Out` might be different, because they can be different type of values.

Comment: "We either use some coins (one or more) of 50 cents, or don't." - I'm a little confused, in the "or don't" part. Why would we assume that we might not want to use the first kind? Why would we want to avoid the first kind for counting the ways?

Comment: @morbidCode it is a possibility. we want to get to the 100. we can *try* to do this *with* a 50 cent coin, or *without* it. both can be a valid choice, we don't know until we try. so we try both - once with, and another, without - and count the number of successes overall  by summing the number of successes in each of the two cases.

Comment: ah, so since we are recursive, first we try to do this with the 50 cent coin, we either use the 50 cent or we don't. Then in both processes, we would do the same with the next denomination, 25 cent coin. In each of those 25 cent coin, we either use that 25 cent coin or we don't. Then in each of those processes, we do the same with the rest of denomination. Is that correct? But it looks like we will have to calculate the same values many times?

Comment: @morbidCode not "with the 50 cent coin", but "with 50 cent coins". *Any* amount of them. Thus, there is no duplication: some solutions have 50-cent coins in them, others don't. We calculate the two values, and sum them up. This is how we "Divide [the problem] to the [non-overlapping] subparts [some of which (but here, the both of them) are] of the same nature", the rule #1 in the other answer here.

Comment: just want to make sure, we aren't just going to do this in 50 cents, we will have to do this on all denomination after 50 cents as we go deeper right? I mean the with coins and without coins?

Comment: @morbidCode right. that's what the equation `ways( sum, k ) = ways( sum, k - 1 )
                 +
                 ways( sum - first_denomination(k),  k )` is telling us.

Comment: got it! This is beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: one of the best explanations for both: the problem and the recursion

Comment: An excellent explanation of the problem, the solution and recursion.

Comment: @SimonBagley thanks! glad to be of help.  (cotemporaneously, someone un-upvoted this same answer. :) if you clicked something unintentionally on this page, just FYI. it happened to me too once or twice :) (phones, thumbs, etc.) )

Answer (score 10):

The first code box in Will Ness' answer above gave me enough insight to understand the algorithm. Once I understood it, I realized I'd probably have got there very quickly by actually seeing what the algorithm does step-by-step.

Below is the graph of how the algorithm proceeds for a simple case. The amount is 6 pence and we have two kinds of coin: five pence (index 2) and a penny (index 1).

Note that the leaf nodes all evaluate to 0 or 1. This is obvious when we look at the condition in the procedure (one of these values is returned, or else the function calls itself again.) Only two leaf nodes evaluate to 1, so there are 2 ways to make 6 pence from these two kinds of coin, i.e. 6 pennies, or a penny and a five pence.

I now understand the algorithm but I still don't see how I would have worked out the algorithm from the initial problem. Maybe, as I read more of the SICP book, this kind of solution will seem more obvious to me.

```
                             (cc 6 2)
                                |
                 -----------------------------------
                 |                                 |
              (cc 6 1)                          (cc 1 2)
                 |                                 |
   ------------------                         --------------
   |                |                         |            |
(cc 6 0)=0       (cc 5 1)                  (cc 1 1)     (cc -4 2)=0
                    |                         |
             -------------             -------------
             |           |             |           |
          (cc 5 0)=0  (cc 4 1)      (cc 1 0)=0  (cc 0 1)=1
                         |
               --------------
               |            |
            (cc 4 0)=0   (cc 3 1)
                            |
                     --------------
                     |            |
                  (cc 3 0)=0   (cc 2 1)
                                  |
                           --------------
                           |            |
                        (cc 2 0)=0   (cc 1 1)
                                        |
                                 --------------
                                 |            |
                              (cc 1 0)=0   (cc 0 1)=1
```

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thanks for fixing the graph. Also: http://grammarist.com/spelling/realise-realize/