# Find tree height using folde function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

One of the assignments I am working on leading up to exams had me create

```
data Exp =  T | F | And Exp Exp | Or Exp Exp | Not Exp deriving (Eq, Show, Ord, Read)
```

Then it asked to make

`folde :: a -> a -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> Exp -> a`

This is what I came up with

```
folde :: a -> a -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> Exp -> a
folde t f a o n T = t
folde t f a o n F = f
folde t f a o n (And x y) = a (folde t f a o n x) (folde t f a o n y)
folde t f a o n (Or x y) = o (folde t f a o n x) (folde t f a o n y)
folde t f a o n (Not x) = n (folde t f a o n x)
```

The assignment asks for `evb`, `evi` and `evh`.

They are all supposed to work with one single call to folde using correct parameters.

Evb evaluates boolean expressions.

```
evb :: Exp -> Bool
evb = folde True False (&&) (||) not
```

Evi evaluates to an integer, treating `T` as `Int 1`, `F` as `Int 5`, `And` as `+`, `Or` as `*` and `Not` as negate.

```
evi :: Exp -> Int
evi = folde 1 5 (+) (*) negate
```

So far so good, it all works. I'll be happy for any feedback on this as well.

---

However, I can't seem to understand how to solve the `evh`.
`evh` is supposed to calculate the heigh of the tree.

It should be `evh :: Exp -> Int`

The assignment says it should treat `T` and `F` as height `1`.
It goes on that `Not x` should evaluate to `height x + 1`. `And` and `Or` has the `height of its tallest subtree + 1`.

I can't seem to figure out what I should pass on to my `folde` function

Comment: Slight improvement for the folde function, if you're not using the arguments, you can replace them with a `_`, which makes the definition a bit easier to read by removing unnecessary bits. example: `folde t _ _ _ _ T = t`

Comment: Hint: what should be the `a` in the `folde` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The assignment says it should treat `T` and `F` as height `1`. It goes on that `Not x` should evaluate to `height x + 1`. `And` and `Or` has the height of its tallest subtree + `1`.

You can write this pretty directly with explicit recursion:

```
height T = 1
height F = 1
height (Not x) = height x + 1
height (And x y) = max (height x) (height y) + 1
height (Or  x y) = max (height x) (height y) + 1
```

Now, how do you write this with `folde`? The key thing about recursive folding is that `folde` gives each of your functions the result of folding all the subtrees. When you `folde` on `And l r`, it folds both subtrees first, and then passes those results into the argument to `folde`. So, instead of you manually calling `height x`, `folde` is going to calculate that for you and pass it as an argument, so your own work ends up something like `\x y -> max x y + 1`. Essentially, split `height` into 5 definitions, one per constructor, and instead of destructuring and recursing down subtrees, take the heights of the subtrees as arguments:

```
heightT = 1 -- height T = 1
heightF = 1 -- height F = 1
heightN x = x + 1 -- height (Not x) = height x + 1
heightA l r = max l r + 1 -- height (And l r) = max (height l) (height r) + 1
heightO l r = max l r + 1 -- height (Or  l r) = max (height l) (height r) + 1
```

Feed them to `folde`, and simplify

```
height = folde 1 1  -- T F
               ao   -- And
               ao   -- Or
               (+1) -- Not
         where ao x y = max x y + 1
```

---

And now for something new! Take this definition:

```
data ExpF a = T | F | Not a | And a a | Or a a
              deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

This looks like your `Exp`, except instead of recursion it's got a type parameter and a bunch of holes for values of that type. Now, take a look at the types of expressions under `ExpF`:

```
T :: forall a. ExpF a
Not F :: forall a. ExpF (ExpF a)
And F (Not T) :: forall a. ExpF (ExpF (ExpF a))
```

If you set `a = ExpF (ExpF (ExpF (ExpF (ExpF ...))))` (on to infinity) in each of the above, you find that they can all be made to have the same type:

```
T             :: ExpF (ExpF (ExpF ...))
Not F         :: ExpF (ExpF (ExpF ...))
And F (Not T) :: ExpF (ExpF (ExpF ...))
```

Infinity is fun! We can encode this infinitely recursive type with `Fix`

```
newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }
-- Compare
-- Type  level: Fix f = f (Fix f)
-- Value level: fix f = f (fix f)
-- Fix ExpF = ExpF (ExpF (ExpF ...))
-- fix (1:) =    1:(   1:(  1: ...))
-- Recover original Exp
type Exp = Fix ExpF
-- Sprinkle Fix everywhere to make it work
Fix T :: Exp
Fix $ And (Fix T) (Fix $ Not $ Fix F) :: Exp
-- can also use pattern synonyms
pattern T' = Fix T
pattern F' = Fix F
pattern Not' t = Fix (Not t)
pattern And' l r = Fix (And l r)
pattern Or' l r = Fix (Or l r)
T' :: Exp
And' T' (Not' F') :: Exp
```

And now here's the nice part: one definition of `fold` to rule them all:

```
fold :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
fold alg (Fix ffix) = alg $ fold alg <$> ffix
-- ffix :: f (Fix f)
-- fold alg :: Fix f -> a
-- fold alg <$> ffix :: f a
-- ^ Hey, remember when I said folds fold the subtrees first?
-- Here you can see it very literally
```

Here's a monomorphic `height`

```
height = fold $ \case -- LambdaCase extension: \case ... ~=> \fresh -> case fresh of ...
  T -> 1
  F -> 1
  Not x -> x + 1
  And x y -> max x y + 1
  Or  x y -> max x y + 1
```

And now a very polymorphic `height` (in your case it's off by one; oh well).

```
height = fold $ option 0 (+1) . fmap getMax . foldMap (Option . Just . Max)
height $ Fix T -- 0
height $ Fix $ And (Fix T) (Fix $ Not $ Fix F) -- 2
```

See the [recursion-schemes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2) package to learn these dark arts. It also makes this work for base types like `[]` with a type family, and removes the need to `Fix` everything with said trickery + some TH.