# Why this implementation of Fibonacci is extremely fast?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fibonacci

This implementation of Fibonacci is easy to understand but very slow:

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Following implementation of Fibonacci is hard to understand but super fast. It calculates 100,000th Fibonacci number instantly on my laptop.

```
fib = fastFib 1 1

fastFib _ _ 0 = 0
fastFib _ _ 1 = 1
fastFib _ _ 2 = 1
fastFib a b 3 = a + b
fastFib a b c = fastFib (a + b) a (c - 1)
```

What the magic is happening here about the latter implementation and how does it work?

Comment: It's tail-recursive, which the first is not. You don't have to keep all the stack frames.

Comment: The first one uses recursion, and branches exponentially (since nearly every call results in two extra calls). The latter is linear, since each call results in at most one call (well the base case of course stops recursion). So this is *O(n)* versus *O(2^n)*

Comment: @JaredSmith: although tail recursion indeed can contribute something, there is a difference in time complexity between the two, which is the major reason why the performance differs.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem of course, you are correct. I guess you could cut a lot of the difference with memoization, since you don't have to pay nearly as much for every double call on the recursion.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: What is the reasoning path to reach this kind of implementations? Why Haskell does not optimize the first one to the second? (links are appreciated)

Comment: Haskell is a language. It lets you expeess algoritms. It doesn't imorove them.

Comment: @n.m. I thought FP is about declarative programming and not to worry about language internals. The fast implementation of Fibonacci is against this. It seems theoretically an FP language should be able to handle such optimizations. Am I wrong on my assumptions?

Comment: @RemisaYousefvand I think, you'll want to read about superoptimization.

Comment: @RemisaYousefvand An implementation *could* cache the return value of every function call (it's theoretically valid), but the overhead of doing so in practice is prohibitive. Now you're asking the compiler to decide *which* functions should be memoized, and that's not something that's easier to specify or determine.

Comment: The second one *isn't* optimized; it simply doesn't need optimization in the first place. Its complexity is linear, not exponential.

Comment: Yes you are wrong on your assumptions.

Comment: What is the source for the second version? Is it even correct? `fib 2 = fastFib 1 1 2 = fastFib (1+1) 1 (2-1) = fastFib _ _ 1 = 1`, but shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: The second one also has more base cases than it really needs. `fastFib a b c | c == 0 | c == 1 = c; | otherwise = fastFib (a + b) a (c - 1)`.

Comment: Oh, I see, only according to the first version `fib 2 = 2`, but actually this is wrong. In the first version, `fib 0 = 1` should be `fib 0 = 0`.

Comment: re: magic, I invite you to peruse [my two answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+magician) on the matter (mostly, the [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19951540/849891)).

Comment: @WillNess: [Great analogy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612470/could-i-ask-for-physical-analogies-or-metaphors-for-recursion/46613542#46613542). So tail optimization is to not report back to your copy (via an accumulator)?

Comment: Simpler `ffb n a = a:ffb (n + a) (n + 1)` -- then `take 50 $ 1:ffb 1 1`

Comment: forget about TR for a moment. :) ---- but yes, TR is: A creates B; then all that's left for A to do is to wait for B's report and return that verbatim, exactly as is; if so, there's no need for A's existence anymore: B can directly report its findings to whomever waited for A to report! but leave it be for a moment; it's orthogonal to what you're asking about, here.

Comment: @fp_mora please don't confuse the asker with the different POV; let them work out what they started here. (and your code is wrong).

Comment: @RemisaYousefvand (replace TR in my comment with TCO, i.e. "tail call optimization").

Comment: The two additions in my function work but don't produce the first two ones. Reduce it to one addition and both ones are produced. `fbf l f = l:fbf f (l + f)` and ` take 20 $ fbf 1 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why is the first implementation slow?

Well it’s slow because each call to `fib` may result in up to two (the average is more like 1.6) calls to `fib`, so to compute `fib 5` you call `fib 4` and `fib 3` which respectively call `fib 3` and `fib 2`, and `fib 2` and `fib 1`, so we can see that each call to `fib (n+1)` results in something like twice as much work as calling `fib n`.

One thing we might observe is that we work out the same thing lots of times, e.g. above we work out `fib 3` twice. That could take a long time if you had to work out e.g. `fib 100` twice.

### How to do fib faster?

I think it’s better to start with this than trying to jump straight into `fastFib`. If I asked you to compute the tenth Fibonacci number by hand, I expect you wouldn’t be computing the third one dozens of times by applying the algorithm. You would probably remember what you had so far. Indeed one could do that for this in Haskell. Just write a program to generate the list of Fibonacci numbers (lazily) and index into it:

```
mediumFib = (\n -> seq !! n) where
  seq = 0:1:[mediumFib (i-1) + mediumFib (i-2)| i <- [2..]]
```

This is much faster but it is bad because it is using a lot of memory to store the list of Fibonacci numbers, and it is slow to find the nth element of a list because you have to follow a lot of pointers.

To compute a single Fibonacci number from scratch (ie not having any computed already) takes quadratic time.

Another way you might compute the tenth Fibonacci number by hand is by writing down the Fibonacci sequence until you get to the tenth element. You then never need to look far in the past or remember all the things you previously computed, you just need to look at the two previous elements. One can imagine an imperative algorithm to do this

```
fib(n):
  if (n<2) return n
  preprevious = 0
  previous = 1
  i = 2
  while true:
    current = preprevious + previous
    if (i = n) return current
    preprevious, previous = previous, current
```

This is just stepping through the recurrence relation:

```
f_n = f_(n-2) + f_(n-1)
```

Indeed we can write it in Haskell too:

```
fastFib n | n < 2     = n
          | otherwise = go 0 1 2 where
  go pp p i | i = n     = pp + p
            | otherwise = go p (pp + p) (i + 1)
```

This is pretty fast now and we can transform this into the function you have too. Here are the steps:

1. Swap the argument order of `pp` (preprevious) and `p` (previous)
2. Instead of counting `i` up, start at `n` and count down.
3. Extract `go` into a top level function because it no longer depends on `n`.

This algorithm only needs to do one sum in each step so it is linear time and that’s pretty fast. To compute `fib (n+1)` is only a small constant more work than computing `fib n`. Compare this to above where it was about 1.6 times as much work.

### Is there a faster `fib`?

Sure there is. It turns out there’s a clever way to express the Fibonacci sequence. We consider the transformation `a,b -> a+b,a` to be a special case of a family of transformations `T_pq`:

```
T_pq : a -> bq + aq + ap
       b -> bp + aq
```

Specifically it is the special case where `p = 0` and `q = 1`. We now can do some algebra to work out if there is a simple way to express applying `T_pq` twice:

```
T_pq T_pq :
  a -> (bp + aq)q + (bq + aq + ap)(q + p)
  b -> (bp + aq)p + (bq + aq + ap)q
=
  a -> (b + a)(q^2 + 2pq) + a(q^2 + p^2)
  b -> b(q^2 + p^2) + a(q^2 + 2pq)
= T_(q^2 + p^2),(q^2 + 2pq)
```

So now let’s write a simple function to compute `T_pq^n (a,b)` and `fib n`

```
tPow p q a b n | n = 1 = (b*q + a*q + a*p, b*p + a*q)
               | otherwise = let (a', b') = tPow p q a b 1 in tPow p q a' b' (n-1)

fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fst $ tPow 0 1 1 0 (n-1)
```

And now we can use our relation to make `tPow` faster:

```
tPow p q a b n | n = 1 = (b*q + a*q + a*p, b*p + a*q)
               | odd n = let (a', b') = tPow p q a b 1 in tPow p q a' b' (n-1)
               | even n = tPow (q*q + p*p) (q*q + 2*p*q) a b (n `div` 2)
```

Why is this faster? Well it’s faster because then computing `fib (2*n)` is only a small constant more work than computing `fib n`, whereas before it was twice as much work and before that it was four times as much work and before that it was the square of the amount of work. Indeed the number of steps is something like the number of bits of `n` in binary plus the number of `1`s in the binary representation of `n`. To compute `fib 1024` only takes about 10 steps whereas the previous algorithm took about 1000. Computing the billionth Fibonacci number only takes 30 steps, which is a lot less than a billion.

Comment: re Fastest Fibonacci, cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48171368/849891)

Answer (score 2):

The magic is reflection, reification, explication of computational process described by the recursive formula:

```
fib 0 = 0    -- NB!
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
      --  n1          n2
      = let {n1 = fib (n-1) ; n2 = fib (n-2)} 
        in n1 + n2
      = let {n1 = fib (n-2) + fib (n-3) ; n2 = fib (n-2)} 
      --            n2          n3
        in n1 + n2
      = let {n1 = n2+n3 ; n2 = fib (n-2) ; n3 = fib (n-3)} 
        in n1 + n2
      = let {n1 = n2+n3 ; n2 = fib (n-3) + fib (n-4) ; n3 = fib (n-3)} 
      --                         n3          n4
        in n1 + n2
      = let {n1 = n2+n3 ; n2 = n3+n4 ; n3 = fib (n-3) ; n4 = fib (n-4)} 
        in n1 + n2
      = let {n1 = n2+n3 ; n2 = n3+n4 ; n3 = n4+n5 ; n4 = fib (n-4) ; n5 = fib (n-5)} 
        in n1 + n2
      = .......
```

, seeing it through to the end case(s), then *flipping the time arrow* (or just reading it from right to left), and coding *explicitly* what's been implicitly going on inside the `let` as part of the recursion's simulated *"call stack"* operations.

Most importantly, replacing equals by equals, aka referential transparency -- using `n2` in place of *each* appearance of `fib (n-2)`, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your answer so I need some time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to make it clear that tail recursion has nothing to do with what makes second program fast. Below, I rewrite your first program to use a proper tail call and we compare the execution time to the second program. I also rewrote that one because it can be simplified quite a bit -

```
fib1 n = slow n id
  where
    slow 0 k = k 0
    slow 1 k = k 1
    slow n k = slow (n - 1) (\a ->
               slow (n - 2) (\b ->
               k (a + b)))

fib2 n = fast n 0 1
  where
    fast 0 a _ = a
    fast n a b = fast (n - 1) b (a + b)
```

The impact on tiny numbers like `n = 10` is negligible -

```
fib1 10
-- 55
-- (0.01 secs, 138,264 bytes)

fib2 10
-- 55
-- (0.01 secs, 71,440 bytes)
```

But even around `n = 20` we notice a huge fall-off in `fib1` performance -

```
fib1 20
-- 6765
-- (0.70 secs, 8,787,320 bytes)

fib2 20
-- 6765
-- (0.01 secs, 76,192 bytes)
```

At `n = 30`, the impact is laughable. Both programs still arrive at the same result, so that's good, but `fib1` takes over 30 seconds. `fib2` still only takes a fraction of a second -

```
fib1 30
-- 832040
-- (32.91 secs, 1,072,371,488 bytes) LOL so bad

fib2 30
-- 832040 (0.09 secs, 80,944 bytes)
```

The reason for this is because the first program, `fib1`, makes *two* recursive calls. The process for this function uses exponential time and space as `n` grows. At `n = 30`, the slow program will make 1,073,741,824 (2<sup>30</sup>) recursive calls. The fast program will only recur 30 times.

At `n = 1000`, we run into a serious problem with `fib1`. Based on the performance of `fib1 30`, we estimate it would take `1.041082353242204e286` *years* to complete 2<sup>1000</sup> recursive calls. Meanwhile, `fib2 1000` handles 1000 recursions effortlessly -

```
fib2 1000
-- 43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875
-- (0.13 secs, 661,016 bytes)
```

---

The original rewrite of your first program might be hard to follow with the added `k` parameter. Use of `Cont` allows us to see the a clear sequence of steps in Haskell's familiar `do` notation -

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

fib1 n = runCont (slow n) id
  where
    slow 0 = return 0
    slow 1 = return 1
    slow n = do
      a <- slow (n - 1)
      b <- slow (n - 2)
      return (a + b)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just obfuscation to hide the fact that the input number is being used as a counter. I would hope that if you saw something like this instead, you'd understand why:

```hs
fib2 n = fastFib2 0 1 0 n

fastFib2 current previous count 0 = 0
fastFib2 current previous count 1 = 1
fastFib2 current previous count n
  | count == n = current
  | otherwise  =
     fastFib2 (current + previous) current (count + 1) n
```

In the code above, we've made the counter explicit: when it equals our input, `n`, we return our accumulator, `current`; otherwise, we keep track in this "forward" recursion of the current and previous numbers (the "[two preceding ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)"), all that is needed to construct the Fibonacci sequence.

The code you shared does the same thing. The `(c - 1)` makes it look like a more traditional "backwards" recurrence, when it's actually starting off the accumulator in the first call, then adding to it.