# How to use Control.Monad.Cont in a recursive function?

Tags: haskell, monads, type-mismatch, continuations, do-notation

I was providing an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54843670/633183) and an idea came to me to use `Cont` monad. I don't know Haskell enough to explain why this program doesn't work

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

fib1 n = runCont (slow n) id
  where
    slow 0 = return 0
    slow 1 = return 1
    slow n = do
      a <- slow (n - 1)
      b <- slow (n - 2)
      return a + b

main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ fib1 10
```

Error -

```
main.hs:10:18: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a2 ~ m a2
    • In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘b’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: return a + b
      In the expression:
        do a <- slow (n - 1)
           b <- slow (n - 2)
           return a + b
    • Relevant bindings include
        b :: a2 (bound at main.hs:9:7)
        a :: a2 (bound at main.hs:8:7)
        slow :: a1 -> m a2 (bound at main.hs:5:5)
   |
10 |       return a + b
   |
```

But this doesn't make sense to me. Why do I have `a2` and `m a2`? I'm expecting `a` and `b` to be of the same type.

It's bugging me because the same program works just fine in JavaScript. Maybe the Haskell one needs a type hint?

```js
const runCont = m => k =>
  m (k)

const _return = x =>
  k => k (x)
  
const slow = n =>
  n < 2
    ? _return (n)
    : slow (n - 1) (a =>
      slow (n - 2) (b =>
      _return (a + b)))
      
const fib = n =>
  runCont (slow(n)) (console.log)
  
fib (10) // 55
```

Comment: `return a + b` is parsed as `(return a) + b`. Try `return (a + b)` or `return $ a + b` instead.

Comment: i knew it had to be something simple :D

Comment: I *highly* recommend putting type signatures for (at least) all top-level functions and bindings. It often makes the type error messages *significantly* easier to understand. Here I would recommend a type signature for the function in the `where` block as well. It also makes the code easier (and faster) to read.

Comment: your `slow` here is actually [essentially applicative](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+essentially+monadic+applicative), not [monadic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39647091/849891): `slow n | n < 2 = pure n ; slow n = [(a+b) | a <- slow (n-1), b <- slow (n-2)] = liftA2 (+) (slow $ n-1) (slow $ n-2)` (using Monad Comprehensions), since no sub-computation depends on / uses the results of no previous sub-computation. so the monad actually does nothing -- it's all just `return`s inside the `do`. for instance `runState (slow 10) 42` returns `(55,42)` so the state isn't used at all.

Comment: (apologies if this is trivial for you by now).

Comment: always appreciate your comments, Will. thanks <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return a + b` parses as `(return a) + b`, whereas you wanted `return (a + b)`. Remember that function application binds tighter than any infix operator.

(It's also common to write `return $ a + b`, which amounts to the same thing)

Comment: why are people upvoting my answer it is boring

Comment: Why did you post the answer in the first place?

Comment: If a question has a trivial solution that can be answered fully in a comment, I just vote to close as "can no longer be reproduced".

Comment: I originally deleted the question, but then saw people already started up-voting this answer. If this answer was useful to others, I didn't want to take away the potential of future readers benefiting as well, so I undeleted it. My apologies if the question was too basic.