# Treating "$" as function application

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I encountered this example while reading [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions).

```
ghci> map ($ 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]  
[7.0,30.0,9.0,1.7320508075688772]
```

I don't quite see how to treat `$` as function application. Does that mean `$` is an operator? But if so, how it will be nested with `+` or `*` in the example? I tried `$ 3 4+`, `$ 4 + 3`, but both raised `parse error on input ‘$’`. How to think of an expression like this in functional programming context?

Comment: You need parentheses to use an infix operator in prefix form: `($ 3) (4+)` should work and give you `7`. So would `($) (4+) 3` (note that the function comes first). In this case it's just a rather clumsy way of writing `4 + 3`

Comment: As for the LYAH example, `($ 3)`  is a "section" of the `$` operator - it's a function which, given a function, applies it to the number `3`. That is then `map`ped over a list of functions.

Comment: if you want to use `$` as [prefix](https://wiki.haskell.org/Infix_operator) operator, you have to use `($)`, also see [section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$` is indeed an operator, defined as:

```
f $ x = f x
-- or equivalently:
($) f x = f x
```

Your expression above is equivalent (by the definition of `map`) to:

```
[($ 3) (4 +), ($ 3) (10 *), ($ 3) sqrt]
```

The parentheses in `($ 3)` and `(4 +)` are not optional. They're part of what's called an [operator section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator). Basically, there are four ways you can use an infix operator (such as `+`):

1. Between two arguments:

   ```
   x + y
   ```
2. Only giving the first argument:

   ```
   (x +)
   -- like \y -> x + y
   ```
3. Only giving the second argument:

   ```
   (+ y)
   -- like \x -> x + y
   ```
4. No arguments:

   ```
   (+)
   -- like \x y -> x + y
   ```

`($ 3) f` evaluates to `f $ 3` evaluates to `f 3`.

`($ 3) (4 +)` evaluates to `(4 +) $ 3` evaluates to `(4 +) 3` evaluates to `4 + 3` evaluates to `7`.

Comment: Haskell users are really supportive of [basic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54849064/633183)! I find this refreshing, tbh.