# Toggle every element in a list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, boolean, non-exhaustive-patterns

I have to write a function that toggles a list of given Booleans for example :

*input : `toggle [True,False,False]`*

*output: `[False,True,True]`*

This is what I came up with

```
toggle :: [Bool] -> [Bool]
toggle [a] = not a:[a]
toggle [] = []
```

And I keep getting this error:

`*** Exception: Uebung3.hs:38:1-20: Non-exhaustive patterns in function toggle`

It's a very basic question, I come from Java and have just started to learn Haskell.

Comment: For an alternative solution, take a look at [map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a pattern, `[a]` is a singleton list: a list containing just one element, `a`.

As a type, `[a]` is a list of `a`-type values. But not as a pattern.

The pattern `(a : as)` stands for a non-empty list with head element `a` and the rest of elements `as`. Use *it* as the pattern in your equation:

```
-- toggle [a] = not a:[a]
toggle (a : as) = not a : _______ as
toggle [] = []
```

You need to complete it by filling in the blanks, to make this definition recursive.

Definitions are *recursive* when they refer to *self* to make a helper call to [continue doing their job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27804489/849891) for the remaining part of their input.

The patterns `[]` (empty list) and `(a : as)` (non-empty list) are mutually exclusive. More, together they are exhaustive: there are no other possibilities for a list value to be.

But the patterns `[]` and `[a]` together are not exhaustive: they do not cover the case of lists of two elements, or longer. The `[a]` pattern is the same as `(a : [])`, a list with an empty list as its tail.