# Understanding reference arguments in recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, reference, pass-by-reference

I have tried implementing the code for Sorted Linked List to BST from leetcode
https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-sorted-list-to-binary-search-tree/ .

The approach which I have used to use a recursive approach like below. But here we have to use reference (&) in head in the function argument. If I don't use, then output will not be correct and gives wrong answer. I am not able to grasp why reference to head is needed here or in what type of recursion scenarios we should do that. I sometimes get confused in recursion.

```
int countNodes(ListNode* head) {
    int count = 0;
    ListNode *temp = head;
    
    while (temp != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

TreeNode *sortedListUtil(ListNode *&head, int n) { 
    // head should be ref, if we dont use & , 
    //   unexpected output will come
    if (n <= 0)
        return NULL;
    
    TreeNode *left = sortedListUtil(head, n/2);
    
    TreeNode *root = new TreeNode(head->val);
    
    root->left = left;
    head = head->next;
    
    root->right = sortedListUtil(head, n - n/2 -1); 
        // recur for remaining nodes
    
    return root;
}

TreeNode* sortedListToBST(ListNode* head) {
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    
    int n = countNodes(head);
    return sortedListUtil(head, n);
}
```

Input linked List is : `head = [-10,-3,0,5,9]`
Output of BST should be this if I use & in head in function argument : `[0,-3,9,-10,null,5]`

If I don't use '&' in function argument then the tree constructed will be :

[-10,-10,-3,-10,null,-3] which is wrong. Root Node should be 0.

Comment: None of this code produces any output, so when you say "output is not correct" we have no idea what you're talking about. A proper [mcve] would go a *long* way to identify what is wrong if you do *not* use a reference. Regarding that, if any caller of `sortedListUtil`, *including itself*, expects the argument to `head` to be modified, a reference is required since you obviously can't exploit using the function return value (you're already using it for something else).

Comment: I've re-tagged. see the "reference" tag info and questions for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortedListUtil` does *two* things: it *returns* the `root` (1), and it also *changes* the `head` (2) so that its invocations *are advancing along the list* from call to the other recursive call:

```
TreeNode *sortedListUtil(ListNode *&head, int n) { 
    // head should be ref, if we dont use & , 
    //   unexpected output will come
    if (n <= 0)
        return NULL;
    
    TreeNode *left = sortedListUtil(head, n/2);
    
    TreeNode *root = new TreeNode(head->val);  // <<<<------ NB (3)
    
    root->left = left;
    head = head->next;  // <<<<--------------------- NB (2)
    
    root->right = sortedListUtil(head, n - n/2 -1); 
        // recur for remaining nodes
    
    return root;        // <<<<--------------------- NB (1)
}
```

Without changing the `head`, each invocation of `sortedListUtil` would look at the same element in the input linked list -- its *head* element.

But this way, for each element that is put into a `ListNode` by `TreeNode *root = new TreeNode(head->val);` (3), the `head` is advanced so that the *next* element from the list will be the one that gets put into the next constructed `ListNode`.

Since `head` is function's parameter, it must be passed by reference `&` so the change is seen by  the caller; otherwise the variable would be local to the function invocation and the change would not be seen by the caller.

Since we've used the list's element, we *must advance the pointer* into the list, so that the *next* list's element is the one that goes next into the next node.

---

*edit:* Where does a given `sortedListUtil` *invocation* change `head`? How many times? Just once! So whatever is done within the "left" invocation(s), the `head` is advanced; then we take *one* element (the one we're at, after the left is filled), advance `head` one notch accordingly, and let the "right" invocation(s) fill the right subtree!

Recursion works like this: assume it works; conclude it works for the smaller case(s) (here, left and right) by the hypothesis (and also, for the smallest case -- where we just return `NULL` and do not touch the `head`); see that adding *small* change by *this invocation* doesn't break things (it doesn't, we properly advance `head` one notch); **then** conclude it works overall!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but still not very clear. I am advancing head by head -> next, but why & is needed. like whenever generally when we call recursively we do fun(root->right) , we don't use ampersand

Comment: this is how function parameters and passing by reference work. without reference you get just local variable. you change it by `head = (head -> next)`, but what you are changing is the variable local to the function. it must be passed by reference so that what's changed is the variable that the _caller_ used when it made the fucntion call: `foo( head, ... )`.

Comment: e.g., `int foo( int i ) { j = i; j = j+1; }`. `j` is changing, but the caller of `int i = 0; foo(i);` doesn't see the change, why, it's `j`, you say, it's a new local variable inside `foo`. right. but the parameter `i` is also local just in the same way.

Comment: only if we pass it by reference, `into foo( int& i) { i = i+1; }`, then `{... ; int i = 0; foo(i); /* now i is 1! */ }`

Comment: I got this example, but I get confused with these types of  recursion scenarios. when there are more than 1 recursive call one after the other and we do something in between/after those  calls.

Comment: where does the function change `head`? how many times? just once! so whatever is done with the "left" invocation, the head is advanced; then we take _one_ element (the one we're at, after the left is filled), advance `head` one notch accordingly, and let "right" invocation to fill the right subtree. recursion works like this: assume it works; conclude it works for the smaller case(s) (here, left and right); see that adding small change by _this invocation_ doesn't break things (it doesn't, we properly advance `head` one notch); **then** conclude it works overall!

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27804489/849891) for general description of what recursion is, at the bottom of the answer. also I invite you to search for my answers on "recursion" tag for more verbiage. :)