# What's the number with the biggest Collatz sequence in a range?

Tags: haskell

I have to write a program using recursion that, given n, returns the minimum value m, 1 ≤ m ≤ n, that generates the longest sequence of Collatz Steps

For example 20, the number that has to return is 18, because 18 and 19 both generate the most amount of steps (20) to 1, but 18 is smaller.
We got a couple examples of what correct answers look like:

```
*Main> longestSequenceTo 13
9
*Main> longestSequenceTo 30
27
*Main> longestSequenceTo 88
73
*Main> longestSequenceTo 1121
871
```

My biggest issue is that we're not allowed to use lists, and our knowledge of Haskell is very basic still.
I've managed to write the collatz conjecture as a function, and I think I know what my condition should be for the recursion on the main function:

```
collatz :: Integer->Integer
collatz 1 = 0
collatz n | even n = 1 + collatz (div n 2)
          | otherwise = 1 + collatz (3*n+1)
```

i think my function should look something like:

```
longestSequence n | collatz n <= collatz (n-1) = 
                  | otherwise =
```

my problem is I dont know how to "store" the actual n, instead of getting the number of steps a number has to take to reach 1

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be answered without just writing the program for you.

Comment: Hint: you could use `max`.

Answer (score 2):

In the way you "think your `longestSequence n` function should look like", you are only comparing the value at `n` with the value at `n-1`. The longest sequence could lie somewhere else. Besides, for each n you calculate the collatz length twice. You only need to calculate the length for `n` and compare it with the maximum value found so far.

Consider the following procedure that will find the maximum sequence length up to n, without using lists:

```
maxLength n = go 0 1
    where
        go z x  | x==n   = z'
                | True   = go z' x'
            where
                value = collatz x
                z' = if value > z then value else z
                x' = succ x
```

You keep track of the max value found so far, with the variable `z`. And you feed the next run with modified values of `x` and `z`. The result is obtained when x is equal to n.

But what you are really after is not the length but who produced that length first... Can you come up with the needed changes to `z` and `z'` to keep track of both a maximum length and the number n that produced it? Try to finish the function below Hint: `z` will have the form of a tuple of (value,x):

```
whoHitsFirstMaxLength n = go ??? 1
    where
        go z x  | x==n   = ???
                | True   = go z' x'
            where
                value = collatz x
                z' = if value > ??? then ??? else z
                x' = succ x
```

Answer (score 1):

First we name the values you operate on, so we can decide what to do with them in a separate step of our thought process:

```
longestSequence n =
  let
    this = collatz n 
    that = collatz (n-1) 
  in
     ....
```

So now we can see you're counting down; let's count up instead:

```
longestSequence n = go 1
  where
  go k = let
           this = collatz k 
           that = collatz (k+1) 
         in
            ....
```

but this only gives us the values of Collatz length for two values; we need them all; recursion to the rescue! --

```
longestSequence n = postprocess $ go 1
  where 
  go k | k > n = (n, -1)
  go k = let
           this = collatz k 
           that = go (k+1) 
         in
            ....
  postprocess x = ...
```

This has the right structure now. It does the `collatz` for `k`, and `longestSequence` for `k+1` (technically, it calls `go`), so that you can compare these results to  create the result for `longestSequence` for *`k`* (technically, this is the result of `go`).

In other words if you know the number between *`k+1`* and *`n`* with the longest sequence (and the length of that sequence), and you know the length of the sequence for *`k`*, you can decide which number between *`k`* and *`n`* has the longest sequence (and also know the length of *that* sequence), and return *that*.

I also wrote [some more answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=recursion%20leap%20faith%20user%3A849891) about the thought process behind the recursion method of problem solving, see if any of them helps.

Comment: sorry, i dont follow, is the first way is enough to make it work, but it should be the second and third way to be optimal? I always end up with the same problem. If i do collatz of n-1, it doesnt mean anything, because there can be a pair of numbers that would have n-1 with higher amount of steps, but still not higher than a previous one. IE 18 has 20 steps, but if i try to check by substracting 1 every time, when i reach 16, which has 4 steps, it will be replaced by 15, which has 17, but its still lower than 18s. thats why i keep thinking i need to "store" 18 to compare against every time

Comment: I gave you a thought process going from your initial piece of code. the last one is the one you should make work. it has the right structure. it does the `collatz` for `k`, and `longestSequence` for `k+1`, then compares the results thus creating the result for `longestSequence` for `k`. I wrote [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=recursion%20leap%20faith%20user%3a849891) about the thought process behind the recursion method of problem solving, see if any of them helps.

Comment: It might make sense to add a sentence for each of these rewrites that describes the thought process that caused them. The motivations are definitely less obvious to those of us not inside your head.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but the way i think about recursions, i try to figure out what is the smallest step my function needs to take, and then, if i take one of those steps, what is the difference between my original expression and one without those steps
so, for example, n!, i need to cover every number between 1 and n, so my smallest necessary step is 1, which makes n!= n-1! + the difference between n! and n-1!, which is n. 

is this the wrong way to think about recursions?

Comment: i also tried finding what the longest sequence for any number between 1 and n is, but i cant figure out how to do it.

a previous exercise asked me to figure out if given 2 numbers n and m, if it was true that every number between 1 and n reached 1 in less than m steps, and i thought that might be a similar idea to this last exercise, but i couldnt figure it out. Also, sorry, but i dont know what any of your code really means, as i dont think we've seen that way of writing recursions yet , i googled what let does, but we only saw where.

Comment: @haskellnoob131 `where` and `let` are the same, here. `foo = ...x... where x=...` is the same as `foo = let x=... in ...x...`. about recursion, see an explanation starting from "The point to (structural) recursion is thinking in the small" in [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27804489/849891) in that link I gave you above.

Comment: @DanielWagner I was hoping that each step is small enough so a reader would see the change easily. the idea was they'd see what's going on on their own; this is always better than just being told the answer, I think. but, I've edited to address your suggestion. :)

Comment: @DanielWagner now that I've written that down, I see counting up instead of down has complicated things unnecessarily here. oh well. for some reason thinking in terms of `foldr` over `[1..n]` felt more natural to me there. :)