# Recursion Issue(I just can't understand what it is doing)

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have been reading multiple articles and as soon as I go to do something recursively I just don't get it, I understand the base case, but I don't get the recursive step. so I have this code which is a solution I found.

```
function range (start, end) {
  if (end < start) return [];
  if(start == end) {
    
    return [start];
                    
  }
  else {
    const numbers =  range(start , end - 1);
    numbers.push(end)
    
    return numbers;
  }
 
}
```

so, I understand the start == end, here is what I do not get.

why is numbers an array? I don't see anywhere that range is an array, I also don't understand if I use start + 1 and push start, the numbers are backward. I have spent 3 weeks so far trying to get a better grasp on recursion and just can not do it, if someone could please help explain to me and maybe offer some resources I have not found? I watched Al Sweigarts recursion video, and thought I understood it until I went to do something, I found it its the recursive step that is just destroying me, I am trying everything I can to understand and get an idea of how this works but I am just super frustrated with myself at this point. thank you for any help.

Comment: `numbers` is an array because it is being assigned the return value of the `range` function, which returns an `Array`. Look at the 3 spots where `return` is being used. All 3 return an Array.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that actually makes sense, I don't know why I have such trouble seeing this. Iteration is no problem for me, but for some reason, I can not wrap my head around recursive thinking.

Comment: Recursion is there [to help us](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27804489/849891) "thinking in the small". (you can skip the specific example at the top of that answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments inline:

```js
function range (start, end) {
  console.log("range function is running with arguments of: ", start, end);
  // If end < start, exit function and return an empty array
  if (end < start) return [];
  
  // If not, check if start and end are equal (with conversion)
  if(start == end) {
    // If so, return an array that only contains the start parameter value and exit
    return [start];                  
  } else {
    // If the above tests are false, call the function again
    // but with end being one less than before and assign either
    // array from above as the value of numbers.
    const numbers =  range(start , end - 1);

    numbers.push(end); // Add end to the end of the array
    return numbers;    // Return this array instead of the other 2
  }
}

console.log("Final array is: ",range(10,20)); // Display the final returned array
```

Comment: Because this question is for an absolute beginner, I have a nitpick for this answer. (1) The first `if` uses an implicit `else` but the second `if` uses explicit `else`. This is inconsistent and only serves to create confusion. (2) The second `if` is redundant, the entire program can be written using a single `if..else`.

Comment: @Mulan This is the OPs code and **he's not asking for it to be altered, he's asking to understand it**. If I change it and then explain that, it won't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: As a beginner, he/she doesn't know where they are going wrong or how they are over-complicating the problem. As an educator, I believe it is our responsibility to help the beginner see these pain points, address them early, and connect the code to terms and concepts that will help them progress beyond the program in question.

Comment: @Mulan As an educator myself (corporate IT training for over 30 years), I generally agree. But, this question is very specific and it's about the code the OP has, not optimized code that he should have. Altering or describing alterations that could/should be taken in this case would add confusion that isn't relevant to the question being asked. The OP wants to know how ***this*** code works.

Comment: @Mulan I thank both of you for what you wrote, but I am open to hearing anything either of you has to say to make this easier for me, I had an idea I may have been overcomplicating it but I was not sure, trying to fully get Recursion has hit me pretty hard and I am trying to get it but struggling on the recursive step part the most, so any more advice from either of you I truly appreciate.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I tried to tag you in the above message as well but it would not let me.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible thing `range` is returning here is `[]` which is an array and `[start]` which is also an array.  So when youre calling `range` recursively from the else block then you'll always end up with an array since there arent any other paths the code can go.

Answer (score 1):

**domain and codomain**

A function's inputs are known as its **domain** and the function's return type is known as its **codomain**. These types can effectively guide us when writing our implementation -

```js
range : (number, number) -> number array
```

**fill in the blanks**

This helpful template can get you started on almost any recursive function. It may seem challenging at first, but things become easier as we fill in the pieces. According to the types for `range`, we already know `2` and `3` **must** return some array -

```js
// range : (number, number) -> number array
function range(start, end) {
  if (...)      // 1
    return ...  // 2 (must return array)
  else
    return ...  // 3 (must return array)
}
```

**1. base case**

Each recursive function needs a **base case**, which does not result in a recursive call, allowing the function to eventually exit. Under what conditions does the `range` function exit?

```js
// range : (number, number) -> number array
function range(start, end) {
  if (end < start) // 1 ✅ when end subceeds start, exit
    return ...     // 2
  else
    return ...     // 3
}
```

**2. base value**

When the exit condition is met, we need to return the base value. Typically it is the empty value of our function's return type, or codomain. Since we **must** return an array, what is the empty value for arrays?

```js
// range : (number, number) -> number array
function range(start, end) {
  if (end < start) // 1 ✅
    return []      // 2 ✅ an empty array is []
  else
    return ...
}
```

**3. inductive case(s)**

We must specify what happens when the exit condition is **not** met in the `else` branch, known as the **inductive cases**. If `end < start` is not `true`, by *induction* we know that `end >= start`. In this case we solve the problem for the current `start` and `end`, and append it to the result of the smaller sub-problem. In other words, if I have `range(P,Q)` the answer is -

```
append Q to the result of range(P, Q - 1)
```

Remember the type for `range` gives us a hint. When `range` is called with new arguments, the first and second arguments are both `number`. The return value will be an array of numbers, or `number array`.

In JavaScript we write that as -

```js
// range : (number, number) -> number array
function range(start, end) {
  if (end < start) // 1 ✅
    return []      // 2 ✅
  else
    return [...range(start, end - 1), end] // 3 ✅ minus and append
}
```

**substitution model**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means writing functions with **referential transparency**, meaning there are no observable side-effects and the function will always return the same value when the same inputs are used. Using the **substitution model** we can substitute any function call for its return value -

```js
range(3,6)
[...range(3, 6 - 1), 6]
[...range(3, 5), 6]
[...[...range(3, 5 - 1), 5], 6]
[...[...range(3, 4), 5], 6]
[...[...[...range(3, 4 - 1), 4], 5], 6]
[...[...[...range(3, 3), 4], 5], 6]
[...[...[...[...range(3, 3 - 1), 3], 4], 5], 6]
[...[...[...[...range(3, 2), 3], 4], 5], 6]
[...[...[...[...[], 3], 4], 5], 6]               // base case
[...[...[...[3], 4], 5], 6]
[...[...[3, 4], 5], 6]
[...[3, 4, 5], 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**using plus instead of minus**

It should be helpful for us to see that we can solve `range` using `+` and prepend instead of `-` and append -

```js
// range : (number, number) -> number array
function range(start, end) {
  if (start > end) // ✅ when start exceeds end, exit
    return []
  else
    return [start, ...range(start + 1, end)] // ✅ plus and prepend
}
```

```js
range(3,6)
[3, ...range(3 + 1, 6)]
[3, ...range(4, 6)]
[3, ...[4, ...range(4 + 1, 6)]]
[3, ...[4, ...range(5, 6)]]
[3, ...[4, ...[5, ...range(5 + 1, 6)]]]
[3, ...[4, ...[5, ...range(6, 6)]]]
[3, ...[4, ...[5, ...[6, ...range(6 + 1, 6)]]]]
[3, ...[4, ...[5, ...[6, ...range(7, 6)]]]]
[3, ...[4, ...[5, ...[6, ...[]]]]]              // base case
[3, ...[4, ...[5, ...[6]]]]
[3, ...[4, ...[5, 6]]]
[3, ...[4, 5, 6]]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**demo**

```js
function rangeplus(start, end) {
  if (start > end)
    return []
  else
    return [start, ...rangeplus(start + 1, end)]
}

function rangeminus(start, end) {
  if (end < start)
    return []
  else
    return [...rangeminus(start, end - 1), end]
}

console.log(rangeplus(3,6))
// [3, 4, 5, 6]

console.log(rangeminus(3,6))
// [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you really think this answer clears things up? You've introduced new syntax (the spread operator) without describing it at all and all kinds of terminology that may make academics feel good to use, but don't add to the actual understanding of the code. This is just a super overcomplicated "answer" loaded with jargon that doesn't actually work with the same code the OP is asking about. This isn't a Comp. Sci. class. As you said yourself, the OP is an absolute beginner. This answer will scare any beginner away.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot understand a recursive algorithm ( not your own ) by reading its lines only.. so, you need to apply a simple example to get the right result and understand where it's goes to, this is my example :

**First call**

start = 1

end = 0

=>start > start
Algorithm result : `return [];`  ===> an empty array

**First call**

start = 1

end = 1

=> start = end
Algorithm result :    `return [start];`      ===> array of ONE element (start value)

**First call**

start = 1

end = 5

=> start < end

in this case the algorithm will call itself    `const numbers =  range(start , end - 1);` by changing the end value and storing it in array called numbers

**Second call :**

numbers = []

range(1,5-1)

(don't forget, "end" (4) is still greater than "start" so it will go to the recall iteration )

**Third call :**

numbers []

range(1,4-1)

=>"end" is still greater (3)

**Fourth call :**

numbers []

range(1,3-1)

=>"end" is still greater (2)

**Fifth call :**
numbers []
range(1,2-1)

=>now, "end"(1) is equals to "start" (1),the next iteration will act differently

**Sixth call :**
start = end ==> this call will return start value (1) and push it to the constant number

so, now, the algorithm will continue the execution of not executed lines after the previous calls (I mean numbers push() ):

Result of `sixth call = 1`
it will push it to numbers, and return numbers (array of one element [1])
Result of `fifth call = 2`
push to numbers ==> numbers is [1,2]
etc. Until it reaches the first call.

Final Result : [1,2,3,4,5]

I hope that it can help.