# Returning first k elements of a list. My code returns last k elements

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml, tail-recursion

I am trying to return the first *k* elements of a list `xs`. For example `take 2 [1; 2; 3]` should output `[1; 2]`.

I wrote a function, but instead of returning the first *k* elements it returns the last *k* elements, and instead of returning the whole list if *k* equals to length of the list, it fails.

This is my code

```
let rec take k = function
|[] -> failwith "take"
|x :: xs -> if k = List.length xs  then xs else take (List.length xs - k) xs
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944969/prolog-accumulators-are-they-really-a-different-concept/19951540#19951540 for some (hopefully helpful) verbiage. It is language-agnostic, contrary to the title. (also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803152/sicp-example-counting-change-cannot-understand/27804489#27804489) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659581/functional-programming-lots-of-emphasis-on-recursion-why/12662393#12662393)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to answer the two basic questions for writing recursively:

1. What cases are so trivial that the answer is obvious?
2. If given a non-trivial case, how do I make a smaller instance of it, so I can get the answer for that smaller instance *just by using this same function that I am writing<sup>1</sup>*, and then find my full answer from that smaller answer by some *simple* steps?

For this problem, the trivial cases (I would say) are when *k* is *0*, and when the given list is an empty list.

For the non trivial case, the insight seems to be that I can get the first *k* elements of a list (for *k > 0*) by getting the first *(k - 1)* elements of the *tail* of the list, and then adding the *head* of the original list onto that *<sup>2</sup>*.

This is not what your code does, so that's basically why it doesn't work :-)

As a side comment, I wouldn't consider it an error to ask for the first *0* elements of any list (including the empty list).

---

*<sup>1</sup>* and the essence of recursion method is to assume you already have it at your disposal.

*<sup>2</sup>* this is because of the identity `length (x :: xs) = 1 + length xs`.

Comment: So I should replace failwith with if k = 0 then [] , and for the second line if k = 0 then [] else take (k-1) xs @ [x] ? I will give it a look again and try to solve it. Right now I can hardly understand any of this :-). Thank you.

Comment: You want to put the head back on the beginning. `take (k - 1) xs @ [x]` puts it at the end. Hint: use the `::` operator. As a side comment, learning to think recursively is a real pleasure (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Just a different way :

```
let take k l =
  let v =Array.of_list l in
  let v'=Array.make k 0 in
  Array.blit v 0 v' 0 k;
  Array.to_list v';;
```

test:

```
# take 2 [1;2;3];;
- : int list = [1; 2]
# take 0 [1;2;3];;
- : int list = []
# take 4 [1;2;3];;
Exception: Invalid_argument "Array.blit".
```